# After filling signup form in html page it gives this error and use username and password and store values in login form

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, typeerror

After filling signup form in html page it gives this error and use username and password and store values in login form.:

```
TypeError at /login/ argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.
```

[image: This is the error]

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class signup(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField();
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=20, primary_key = True)
    department= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    pic=models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100, default='default.png')
    created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class login(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    login= models.DateTimeField(_('last_login'),auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import signup
from .models import login

class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
            model=login
            fields=['username','password']


class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
            model=signup
            fields=['username','full_name', 'email','department','password','pic']
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import  SignUpForm
from .forms import  loginForm
from django.db import connection

def home(request):
    title= 'welcome'
    form = SignUpForm(data = request.POST or None)
    print(form.is_valid)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        print(instance)
        print(instance.email)
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form,           
    }       
    return render(request,"base.html", context)

def login(request):
    form = loginForm(data = request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        username=instance.username
        password=instance.password
        row=auth(username,password)
        if password in row:
            instance.save()
            form1=SignUpForm
            context={
                "form":form1,
                "instance":instance
            }
            return render(request, "profile.html", context)
    title= 'welcome back'
    context ={
        "title":title,
        "form":form    
    }       
    return render(request, "login.html", context)

def auth(username,password):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM teacher_signup WHERE username = %s", [username])
    row = cursor.fetchone()    
    return row
```

when click on signup button [if password in row:] this line is called somehow.

[image: signup page]

Comment: _not iterable_ sounds like you are trying to loop with one of the arguments. try some debug statement to figure out what is missing.

Comment: @RohitChopra which line is it?

Comment: why are you doing raw sql here? I dont see any need for it in django except you need something what django cannot do as orm

Comment: line32.              if password in row:

Comment: I m using raw sql to get username and password from table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiple mistakes in views:

```
def login(request):
    form = loginForm(request.POST or None) # <-- corrected
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        username = instance.username
        password = instance.password
        row = auth(username,password)
        if password in row:
           instance.save()
           form1 = SignUpForm() # <-- you forgot () 
           context={
              "form":form1,
              "instance":instance
           }
           return render(request, "profile.html", context)             

   title= 'welcome back'
   context ={
       "title":title,
       "form":form
   }
   return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

Comment: and dont name the variables with `form1` or `form2` this is very bad naming and can cause you lots of headache later

Comment: `row` is not an iterable and `in` needs something iterable and hence the error you are getting. why dont you use normal usual django orm to get the username and password from db? it is really weird to use raw sql here.

Comment: I do not know how to use orm method.

Comment: @RohitChopra please read this first: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/ before continuing with your project

Comment: But the data is saving in signup form. Is it because of this error?

Comment: It is not working after removing raw SQL queries. Values of signup form is saving in login form.

Comment: @RohitChopra it is not about just removing the raw sql, but rewriting it in django orm, so you can see what is really going on and what the `row` is which is being returned from your query